# Rewrite URL on specific condition only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Am trying to create a rewrite rule and struggling from couple of days.

My condition should be in such a way that if in the url after authorbio ONLY ONE WORD is found then leave it as it is. for all remaining conditions it should remove authorbio/

The conditions 2 & 3 in below example are generic and can be done easily but it should be done along with condition#1 in example

**Example:**

- THIS SHOULD REMAIN AS IT IS:

  /mainblog/authorbio/authorname

  SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

  /mainblog/authorbio/authorname
- WHERE AS THIS SHOULD REMOVE AUTHORBIO FROM THE URL

  /mainblog/authorbio/someblog/blogarticle

  SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

  /mainblog/someblog/blogarticle
- Also THIS SHOULD REMOVE AUTHORBIO FROM THE URL

  /mainblog/authorbio/

  SHOULD BE CHANGED TO

  /mainblog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/mainblog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mainblog/

RewriteRule ^authorbio/?$ /mainblog/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^authorbio/([^/]+/.+)$ $1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added this to the bottom of my existing .htaccess rules and restarted apache, it's not working not even satisfying any condition. FYI::: am using wordpress MU setup with varnish as caching technique. In varnish am already using one rewrite that is to replace the /authors to /mainblog/authorbio. so any request to /authors/somename comes to wordpress as /mainblog/authorbio/somename........I have verified this by printing the request URL....

Comment: Place them **before your existing** rules.